# Ruby gem indicative of not being installed even though it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm having trouble running rails on Snow Leopard after having installed flutie and formtastic.
Essentially I added the following lines into the Gemfile:

> ```
> gem 'formtastic', '~> 1.1.0'
> gem 'flutie', '1.1.1'
> ```

After running bundle install these are then installed in the output. Infact bundle check runs correctly also:

> ```
> The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
> ```

Even running bundle list shows that the two gems are installed:

> ```
>  * flutie (1.1.1)
>  * formtastic (1.1.0)
> ```

HOWEVER! When I try to run any rails command, I get the following error message:

> ```
> Could not find flutie-1.1.1 in any of the sources
> Try running `bundle install`.
> ```

I have run rake flutie:install after installation and was trying to run the formtastic installation through rails.

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated!

NB: The rails version I'm running is 3.0.1 and ruby version is 1.9.2p0. I compiled this from source on OS X 10.6.4. The same versions on a Win7 box seem to work fine!

Comment: It's always the same problem that A lot of report it with mac and gem. Use RVM and your problem can be solved.

Comment: +1 to @shingara, using rvm will most likely fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll give it a go (learning RVM at the same time!) and then update the question appropriately.

Comment: @shingara - I don't suppose you want to post your solution as an answer so I can accept it? It definitely worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what was happening however installing RVM fixed the problem. I highly recommend anyone else having problems with Ruby on a Mac tries RVM first!